# Parse coordinates from JSON response

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, json, ipad

I have JSON with data

```
> {
>     "a": {
>         [{"X":12,"Y":6},{"X":24,"Y":9},{"X":91,"Y":23},{"X":36,"Y":79},{"X":69,"Y":71},{"X":55,"Y":19}],
>         "roam": true,
>         "device": true
>     } }
```

I used

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {   
    [super viewDidLoad];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];       
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://josn-example/json.json"]];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];            
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    [responseData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {      
    [connection release];

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Response String : %@", responseString);

    [responseData release];

    NSError *error;
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSArray *luckyNumbers = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
    NSLog(@"luckNumber : %@",luckyNumbers);

    [responseString release];   

    if (luckyNumbers == nil)
        label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"JSON parsing failed: %@", [error localizedDescription]];
    else {      
        NSMutableString *text = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Lucky numbers:\n"];

        for (int i = 0; i < [luckyNumbers count]; i++) 
            [text appendFormat:@"%@\n", [luckyNumbers objectAtIndex:i]];

        label.text =  text;
    }
}
```

I am trying to parse the X and Y coordinates and put a imageview on those coordinates. Please advise how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Go to json.org and spend five minutes learning the syntax.  Then compare the JSON to the corresponding NSLog dump so you understand how they look similar but not identical.  Then use dictionary and array accesses to reach the data.  It's very simple if you only try and not look for a "cookbook".

Comment: i m getting response in nslog,that is not the problem. The issue is i want to seperate the coordinates,so that i can put image on those coordinates.

Comment: You say you have the response, implying you've parsed it.  If you understand the structure of JSON you will understand how to separate it -- it's just peeling the layers of the onion, one at a time, and understanding what each layer means and how it's structured.

Comment: Hint:  What is the outermost structure of the JSON?  If your JSON above is even partway correct it's not an NSArray.

Answer (score 0):

First off, The JSON snippet that is shown above is not a valid JSON. Here is a valid counterpart {
    "a": [
        {
            "X": 12,
            "Y": 6
        },
        {
            "X": 24,
            "Y": 9
        },
        {
            "X": 91,
            "Y": 23
        },
        {
            "X": 36,
            "Y": 79
        },
        {
            "X": 69,
            "Y": 71
        },
        {
            "X": 55,
            "Y": 19
        }
    ],
    "roam": true,
    "device": true
}.

Assuming you have a valid JSON, you can then use NSJSONSerialization to convert the string to a FOundation object (NSDictionary) that you can then easily process.
Sample snippet (assume "json" holds the json String:

```
    NSData* jsonData = [json dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSError* error ;
    id jsonObj = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
    NSLog (@"JSON Is %@ : Error is %@",jsonObj, error);
```

Comment: He's using SBJSON to parse, and that should provide the equivalent to the NSJSONSerialization parsing.